# Layout CardView pre-Lollipop e Lollipop effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I implement for my listview a cardview layout for items.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Titolo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="#ccdbe5"
        android:textColor="#004B7D"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Sottotitolo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is the effect in pre-lollipop is ok, i see very clear the card. But in the Lollipop device i not see very well.

How i can fixed this?
[image: Lollipop]
[image: No Lollipop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found i solution..sorry if i answer my own question.

This is resolve the problem:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >
```